# Pass variable to datapoints in canvasjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5-canvas, canvasjs

I am trying to make line garph from canvasjs using database data. But I am having problem with passing data to datapoints.

```
 $.ajax({
    dataType : "json",
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'index.php/dashboard/line_graph',
    data: {},
    success: function(data)
    {
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
        {
            var firstdate = data[i].nextdate;
            var res = firstdate.replace(/[-]/g,','); 
            fd += '{ x: new Date(' + res + '), y:' + data[i].count +'},';
        }
        var fin = fd.slice(0,-1);
         finals = "[" + fin + "]";            
                var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",
                  {

                    title:{
                    text: "Booking - per month (DEMO)"
                    },
                     data: [
                    {
                      type: "line",

                      dataPoints: finals

                    }
                    ]
                  });

                  chart.render();

    }
});
```

When I alert `finals` and copy paste the alerted data to datapoints and run then its working. But when variable containing same data is passed to datapoint then its not working.

In console log, I get this error.

```
 TypeError: l.dataPoints[q].x is undefined
```

The format of the datapoints is this. And variable `finals` also contains same data when I do alert.

```
 [
 { x: new Date(2015,03,6), y:4},
 { x: new Date(2015,03,11), y:0},
 { x: new Date(2015,03,16), y:0},
 { x: new Date(2015,03,21), y:0},
 { x: new Date(2015,03,26), y:0},
 { x: new Date(2015,03,31), y:14}
 ]
```

My page returns this json_encode format.

```
 [
 {"firstdate":"2015-03-01","nextdate":"2015-03-6","count":"4"},    
 {"firstdate":"2015-03-6","nextdate":"2015-03-11","count":"0"},
 {"firstdate":"2015-03-11","nextdate":"2015-03-16","count":"0"},
 {"firstdate":"2015-03-16","nextdate":"2015-03-21","count":"0"},
 {"firstdate":"2015-03-21","nextdate":"2015-03-26","count":"0"},
 {"firstdate":"2015-03-26","nextdate":"2015-03-31","count":"14"}
 ]
```

I don't get the issues. Please Help.

Comment: Hi, can you add what data your page `index.php/dashboard/line_graph` returns ?

Comment: Hi i had edited my question. linegraph returns json format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create `finals` variable like a string, you can use directly object format of Javascript :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: base_url + 'index.php/dashboard/line_graph',
    data: {},
    success: function(data)
    {
        var tabData = JSON.parse(data);
        var finals = [];
        for(var i = 0; i < tabData.length; i++)
        {
            var firstdate = tabData[i].nextdate;
            var res = firstdate.split('-'); 
            finals.push({ 'x': new Date(res[2],res[1],res[0]), 'y': tabData[i].count });
        }
        var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer",{
            title:{
                text: "Booking - per month (DEMO)"
            },
            data: [
                {
                    type: "line",
                    dataPoints: finals
                }
            ]
        });

        chart.render();
    }
});
```

Comment: Maybe you will have to convert `tabData[i].count` to Integer with [`parseInt` function](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Don't create every thing as a string:

```
var finals = [];
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
    var firstdate = data[i].nextdate;
    var res = firstdate.replace(/[-]/g,','); 
    finals.push({ x: new Date(res), y: parseInt(data[i].count)});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can build your array data in view, using loop from variable of php, for example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     var current_month = [];
     <?php foreach ($grafico_current as $key => $value) { ?>
        current_month.push({ 'x': new Date(<?php echo $value['ano']; ?>,<?php echo $value['mes']; ?>,<?php echo $value['dia']; ?>), 'y': <?php echo $value['total']; ?> });
     <?php } ?>
 </script>
```

After it, set the dataPoint with this new var:

> dataPoints: current_month

Answer (score 0):

CanvasJS only allows you to pass things like x,y,label, IndexLabel. So if you want to pass the ID (or multiple ids) of drilldown data, you can't. I tried to think of a way around this. The only thing that I have come up with was to create a dummy series. I set the indexLabel to the dummy series to be a JSON string of data. Then when I click, I can get the y axis index from e.dataPointIndex

```
DATA.push({ showInLegend: false, markerType: 'none',label: 
d[i].cv_quality_metric_period_ending, y:   parseFloat((Math.round(  
d[i].cv_quality_metric_value * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)), indexLabel: '{"metric_id":' + metric_id + '}'  });
```

The series that has the click function looks like this:

```
R4Q.push({ label: d[i].cv_quality_metric_period_ending, indexLabel: 
d[i].cv_quality_metric_R4Q, y:  parseFloat((Math.round(  
d[i].cv_quality_metric_r4q * 100) / 100).toFixed(2)) ,click: function(e){ 
chartClickHandler( metric_id, e) },markerColor: markerColor, 
markerType:markerType,markerSize: markerSize});
```

The metric_id is the same for all data, so it is correct and accessible.

Then I can look up the data for that column in the dummy series by referencing
var index = e.dataPointIndex //clicked y column starts at 0 so 2 is the 3rd y column of data.

```
function chartClickHandler(metric_id,e){
var index = e.dataPointIndex
var data = e.chart.data[2].dataPoints[index].indexLabel
data = JSON.parse(data)
//do what you need to do with the passed data
}
```

In the JSON that constructs the chart I add the dummy series

```
{
        name: "data", 
        type: "spline",       
        showInLegend: false,        
        legendMarkerType: 'none',        
    visible:false,
        dataPoints: DATA
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

Pass data like
dataPoints: JSON.parse(data)

instead of 
dataPoints: data